Convert Foxpro .dbf file to excel via ms access
So I'm currently trying to convert a foxpro .dbf table from an mrp system my company uses (PCMRP) to an excel spreadsheet via my Access application using ADO and an ODBC connection. I'm getting the following error: Could not find file "C:\users\temp\PartMast.mdb". See code below. In no way am i referencing PartMast.mdb in my code. When debugging, the docmd.transferspreadsheet line is where it is getting tripped up. I think it has to do with the tempQueryforExport because when the code stops at the docmd.transferspreadsheet line, the query shows up in the Access Objects in the left pane. When i try to run that query it gives the same error. Any ideas on why this is happening/ how to fix this?
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim strconnect As String
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim dbfFolder As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQL As String
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim tempqueryname As String
Dim db As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef
tempqueryname = "tmpQueryforExport"
dbfFolder = "C:\Users\temp\PC MRP"
strconnect = "DSN=pcMRPVFP;SourceDB=u:\PC MRP;SourceType=DBF;Exclusive=No;BackgroundFetch=Yes;Collate=Machine;Null=Yes;Deleted=Yes;"

filename = "PARTMAST.dbf"
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open strconnect
cn.Execute "SET REPROCESS TO 10 SECONDS"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
SQL = "SELECT * from PartMast.dbf order by partno;"
rs.Open SQL, cn
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(tempqueryname)
qdf.SQL = SQL
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, tempqueryname, dbfFolder & "\" & Left(filename, 8) & ".xls", 1

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
db.QueryDefs.Delete tempqueryname
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing




End Sub


I would try to create a linked table from Access. Once that works, then Access and VBA code will simply see the table as a standard Access table.  Access does still have support for dbase tables, and if you can link the table, then transfers into a Access table, or even transfers into Excel becomes rather easy

@Albert D. Kallal I'm the only one who has the VFP9 odbc driver installed which is needed to create a linked table. The idea was to run this daily in the morning (from my PC) and store the excel files in a shared location so that everyone else in the company can access the data without the odbc driver. I agree that a linked table is the way to go, but for some reason I haven't been able to convince the powers that be to install the drivers on all devices that would need it. Seems like it would be a simple task for IT to remote in and set up the drivers. This is my way of a workaround

Very well. Without question, Excel is a real Swiss army knife, and can read xml, json, dBase and just about anything else on planet earth. I would try linking using the built in Access dBase driver - if it works, then you could eliminate the use of Excel in this process.  If that is a VFP driver is required, then you could still use a transfer database command from the linked table to actual tables in Access. From that point onwards, you working with Access tables. However,  If you fine and ok with resulting Excel data, then that's ok too. I would test/try the built-in dBase/Access driver.

@AlbertD.Kallal the native Dbase driver for access doesn't work for these tables, the fox pro odbc driver has to be installed to access the .dbf tables. I could try your transfer database idea, I'm sure that will work. But I still want to figure out why my code isn't working in case I'm forced to export to excel in the future for whatever reason. I know the connection string is working because i checked the first record in the recordset via msgbox() and it showed the correct value. Just don't know why it's looking for PartMast.mdb tho my source table is PartMast.dbf (see filename in code)

So I realized where I went wrong... forget the ADO recordset entirely. I wasn't passing the ODBC connection string to my querydef.....
See working code below:
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim dbfFolder As String
Dim SQL As String
Dim tempqueryname As String
Dim db As Database
Dim qdf As QueryDef

tempqueryname = "tmpQueryforExport"
dbfFolder = "C:\Users\tburell\temp\PC MRP"
SQL = "SELECT * from PartMast.dbf order by partno;"

Set db = CurrentDb
On Error Resume Next
    db.QueryDefs.Delete tempqueryname
On Error GoTo 0

Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(tempqueryname)
qdf.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=pcMRPVFP;SourceDB=u:\PC MRP;SourceType=DBF;Exclusive=No;BackgroundFetch=Yes;Collate=Machine;Null=Yes;Deleted=Yes;"
qdf.SQL = SQL 

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, tempqueryname, dbfFolder & "\" & Left(filename, 8) & ".xls", 1

db.QueryDefs.Delete tempqueryname
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
end sub

For people struggling with the ODBC string what I did is link the table manually to access, open the table in design view, copy the string from the 'description' field in the table properties sheet, then paste it in your code.
If you obtained the string using the method i just described and you want to create the connection to a table directory rather than to a specific table, then just remove everything after 'Deleted=Yes;'. See below:
below creates a connection only to the table "partmast"
"ODBC;DSN=pcMRPVFP;SourceDB=u:\PC MRP;SourceType=DBF;Exclusive=No;BackgroundFetch=Yes;Collate=Machine;Null=Yes;Deleted=Yes;;TABLE=partmast"

below creates a connection to U:\PCMRP which is a directory containing all my .dbf files
"ODBC;DSN=pcMRPVFP;SourceDB=u:\PC MRP;SourceType=DBF;Exclusive=No;BackgroundFetch=Yes;Collate=Machine;Null=Yes;Deleted=Yes;"

the latter connection string allows you to use the same connection string for different tables in that directory (in my case "U:/pcmrp"), just change your SQL string used to define your querydef to select different tables from that directory.
